# Does it make sense to relax the definition of convergent sequence?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

The usual definition of a convergent sequence is:

A sequence $\{a_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ converges to $c \iff \forall \epsilon \gt 0$ there exists an $N_\epsilon$ such that $|a_n - c| \le \epsilon$ for all $n \ge N_\epsilon$

The intuitive idea is that a sequence converges to $c$, if after a certain point all $a_n$ stay within a given distance $\epsilon$ of $c$. Now consider the following sequence:

$$
\{a_n\}_{n=1}^\infty = \begin{cases}
 1 \quad \text{if } n = 2^k \text{ for some } k \in \mathbb{N} \\
 \frac{1}{n} \quad \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$

This sequence obviously doesn't converge to 0 according to the usual definition because there's always a large $N$ for which $a_N = 1$.

However, these $N$s are very sparse: There's only one for each doubling of $a_n$. In particular, as $n \to \infty$, these outliers become "infinitely sparse". If "$n = \infty$", then we'd need to wait for "another $\infty$" elements until convergence is violated again.

(I took this idea from slowly varying functions where, intuitively speaking, a function is slowly varying if it "converges at $\infty$". Intuitively, $ln(x)$ is slowly varying because as $x \to \infty$  it takes larger and larger $x$ to produce a relevant increase in $ln(x)$.)

Has there been research using a relaxed definition of convergence, such that the above (and similar) sequences $\{a_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ are convergent in this sense? If yes, are there interesting insights from this?

Comment: We have liminf and limsup for such situations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The notion already exists, it is called **convergence in density**. It is quite useful.

A sequence $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ *converges in density* if there exists $x$ such that for each $\varepsilon>0$ we have
$$
\lim_{m\to\infty}\frac1m{\rm card}\bigl\{n\in\{1,\ldots,m\}:|x_n-x|\ge\varepsilon\bigr\}=0.
$$

The notion goes back at least to the paper
[B. Koopman and J. von Neumann, *Dynamical systems of continuous spectra*, PNAS USA, **18** (1932), 255-263](https://www.pnas.org/content/18/3/255).